# Symfony2- submit button causes 'extra fields' error

Tags: php, symfony

I have a simple form:

```
class SignInType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('_username', 'text');
        $builder->add('_password', 'password');
        $builder->add('Sign in', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sign_in';
    }
}
```

which I call in my 'sign-in' action:

```
public function signInAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new SignInType(), null,
        [ 'action' => $this->generateUrl('my_project_account_sign_in_process') ]
    );
```

However binding the POST request results in an invalid form, with an error of `This form should not contain extra fields`. It seems to be the submit button that's causing the issue - how can I resolve this?

```
public function signInProcessAction(Request $request)
{
    $doctrineManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new SignInType());

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    ...
```

Comment: Please provide the twig you use to display form. And what the meanning of the createAction ?

Comment: @Healkiss my Twig view simply contains `{{ form(form) }}`. Sorry, `createAction` was a typo when I transposed my example - now fixed.

Comment: `$this->createForm(new SignUpType(), new SignUp())` is another typo error ? Because we can't be sure that SignUpType === SignInType.

Comment: Ok, somes remarks : why no name for your SignInType ? Where are you modifying the action of your form ? I never seen your "way" to do it.

Comment: First, set the action to your form adding 

in your type `$builder->setAction($this->generateUrl('my_project_account_sign_in_process'))`

or in your twig `{{ form(form, {'action': path('my_project_account_sign_in_process'), 'method': 'POST'}) }}`

Are you sure to be in your signInProcessAction after the submission?

Comment: I'm already setting the form action in my signInAction, which is definitely working.

Comment: Great ! Symfony is magic. I just learn that trick :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51040/discussion-between-jonathan-and-healkiss)

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this by removing the space from my button's name:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    ...
    $builder->add('Sign_in', 'submit');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then the error `This form should not contain extra fields` is surely caused by the form which have no name. Symfony can't get form fields and try to get some random other element ?

Comment: Setting a name makes no difference. The error specifically says it's the submit button ('Sign in') that is extraneous, and therefore the issue.